# How do I stop Sequel's postgres-pr adaptor from returning data in the wrong encoding?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, encoding, sequel

I'm getting the wrong encoding from the [jeremyevans-postgres-pr](https://github.com/jeremyevans/postgres-pr) adaptor, which is one of the ones Sequel recommends.

**Is there something that I'm doing wrong?**

*Example Code:*

```
require 'postgres-pr/connection'
c = PostgresPR::Connection.new('blah', 'blah', 'blah')

row = c.query("select name, cost from remedium.prescription").rows.last
row.each do |f|
  #f.force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_8) #-- uncomment this to 'fix' everything ;/

  enc = f.kind_of?(String) ? f.encoding : ''
  puts [f.class, f, f.inspect, enc].join(' ')
end
```

*Output:*

```
String Paracelsium "Paracelsium" ASCII-8BIT
String £0.00 "\xC2\xA30.00" ASCII-8BIT
```

Needless to say, I get the same results from Sequel itself. And my database isn't encoded to ASCII, but UTF8.

- Right now I need to talk to PostgreSQL using both Ruby and JRuby, and it makes sense to try and use the same toolchain in each case, so this is the obvious adapter to use.  But.
- The [original adaptor](https://github.com/mneumann/postgres-pr) that Jeremy forked behaves the same.
- I can fix this by forcing the encoding across the board, but this will be a royal pain to do across all my code...

---

*Some additional answers I probably should have provided (thank you):*

- versions -> Centos 7; Ruby 2.3.1 & JRuby 9.1.1.0; gem version 0.6.6
- OS locale -> "LANG=en_GB.UTF-8"
- Ruby defaults -> Encoding.default_internal = nil; default_external = Encoding::UTF-8

Comment: What Ruby version are you using? What OS and what locale setting does it have?
What is the output of Encoding.default_internal and Encoding.default_external?
What if you run the script like: "ruby -E UTF-8 myscript.rb"

Comment: Good questions, thank you.  The general stuff I have answered above. As to your last question: no change...

Comment: Just to be sure: can you check the output of "psql -l"? Should show the encoding of your DBs.

Answer (score 1):

`postgres-pr` doesn't support encodings.  It's not something I plan to add myself, but I'd be willing to consider patches.

You can use the `force_encoding` Sequel::Model plugin to fix the encoding, at least for places where you are using models.

Comment: Fair enough.  Any idea why it is defaulting to ASCII?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code sample on one of my DBs and everything worked as expected.
Might be something special to your setup? You can check client encoding with

```
p c.query("SHOW client_encoding;").rows.first
```

And should be able to set it using:

```
p c.query("SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF-8';")
```

After some feedback by Andy Jones and the comment by Jeremy I looked into the source code a bit more. Editing the question so I have better formatting options than as comment.

The driver reads **US-ASCII** from the stream like so:

```
    buffer.copy_from_stream(stream, length-4)
```

[source code](https://github.com/mneumann/postgres-pr/blob/master/lib/postgres-pr/message.rb#L56)

This in turn calls `Buffer#write` which inserts the data into it's own `@content`:

```
@content[@position, sz] = str
```

[source code](https://github.com/mneumann/postgres-pr/blob/master/lib/buffer.rb#L61)

Now @content is a string of specific size, filled with **#** signs and it is created like this:

```
def self.of_size(size)
  raise ArgumentError if size < 0
  new('#' * size
end
```

This makes `@content` a **UTF-8** String, given your system is setup to use UTF-8. Merging a  **US-ASCII** String into a **UTF will result in a __UTF-8** string. From there on, no conversion takes place so it should stay in that encoding. The column content is read using the `Buffer.read` method which does this:

```
@content[@position, n]
```

[source code](https://github.com/mneumann/postgres-pr/blob/master/lib/buffer.rb#L46)

This lengthy explanation just to say: I don't understand why you are seeing **US-ASCII** output :-(

UNLESS: your system is not setup to use UTF-8 in some strange way.

Default encoding was **US-ASCII** with Ruby 1.9 and changed to **UTF-8** with Ruby 2.2 (or earlier, not sure?).

Do you have an

```
# encoding:
```

style comment in the beginning of the file?

What happens if you do

```
puts String.new.encoding
```

What is the value of

```
puts __ENCODING__
```

What is the value of

```
puts RUBY_VERSION
```

Please check in the same file that you run the db test script.

Comment: Regrettably you are only half-right.  I can indeed set the encoding like this, and when I show the encoding as you suggest, it confirms that the encoding has changed. .... *and then it continues to return the data with the ASCII encoding, unchanged*...

Comment: Too bad. "It works on my machine"(tm). Using Ruby 2.2.x.

Comment: You have to admit, it's pretty impressive that it works on your machine, given that the maintainer himself answered this question saying that encodings are not supported ;)

Comment: @AndyJones

I'm running the script provided by the OP and it shows UTF-8. Which kind of makes sense: ruby defaults encoding to UTF-8 since quite a while and my OS locale is UTF-8 as well as is the DB that I access.
I also looked into the source code of the gem. And could not find that the encoding is forced to ASCII. So i'd actually expect UTF-8.

I've read the comment by Jeremy. I think he meant that encoding is not supported to be changed/enforced on the client.

Probably Jeremy can give some more insight...

Comment: Well, all this is true for me too, and I don't get the same results, so something else must be going on, at least for one of us.  I'm far from an expert here, but I thought that the default encoding only applied to "actual Strings", not strings built up from binary data -- which would indeed have an encoding of  ASCII-8BIT, which basically means "Ruby doesn't know"?

Comment: Yes.... it's strange. I looked into it a bit more and updated the answer. Would be interested if you can read it and check the questions.

Comment: Figured it out -- check out my answer.  TL;DR: internal encoding <> external encoding ...

Answer (score 0):

The key to understanding what is happening here is the multiple settings for encoding in ruby. There is:

- the locale encoding set using the magic comment or the -k command line switch.
- the default external encoding, set with `Encoding.default_external` or --external-encoding or -E
- the default *internal* encoding, set with `Encoding.default_internal` or --internal-encoding (or -E after a colon)

Ruby will by default set a string to the internal or external encoding based on some fairly messy rules.  See [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Encoding.html) for details. But the important part here is that when a string is created from binary data it appears to be the internal not the external encoding that is used.

My internal encoding is nil, so that wasn't happening.  (ASCII-8BIT is the encoding that you get when Ruby doesn't know what the encoding is -- it basically means "this is just data to me; good luck reading it".)

If I pass `--internal-encoding UTF-8` on the command line, the problem goes away.  In a sense, then, this has nothing to do with Jeremy's gem.

When I put `-E UTF-8` on the command line, that set the default *external* encoding.  Which did nothing in this case.

EDIT: It worked in this case, but under some (all?) circumstances Ruby will *transcode* the string to the internal encoding, rather than just setting the encoding value as in `force_encoding`.  This stuff is hard.